# Change Xenserver 6.5 Pool Master

Tags: virtual-machines, xen, high-availability, xenserver, host

I'm looking to change the **pool master** because my current pool master is having some hardware issues. I've **disabled HA** and I came across this script to change the pool master to my other server: **xe pool-designate-new-master host-uuid=[uuid]**

My question is this: will changing the pool master **take down the host** (current pool master) or **take down any of the VM's** I've got running on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the pool master won't take down the host or any of the VMs. It will cause a restart of the management service (XAPI) of all pool hosts, so that management access via Citrix XenCenter or CLI (xe commands) won't work for 10-30 seconds. Once the service is restarted, you can reconnect to the poolmaster or a slave via XenCenter (you'll be redirected to the new master).